# PHP / PECL command line

Tags: php, pecl

I'm trying to install a pecl package over a command line. I'm going through a hosting company (who is being absolutely no help to me), and because I am going through a hosting company, I do not have access to the root

Here's my problem. The original PHP version that was installed is 4.4.9, however every time I go to install my package I get the following error:

```
pecl/oauth requires PHP (version >= 5.1.0), installed version is 4.4.9
pecl/oauth requires PHP extension "hash"
```

Seems straight forward enough. If I run php -v I get the following:

```
PHP 4.4.9 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jan 14 2014 12:10:11)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies
```

Okay, that makes sense as to why my install is failing. However, I was told to use php6 -v to check the actual version that is being used, in which I get:

```
PHP 5.4.28 (cgi-fcgi) (built: May  5 2014 19:10:31)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

I can I configure this so when I go to install my pecl package, it will use the php6 and not the older version of php?

Answer (score 0):

from this [link](http://docs.1h.com/How_to_switch_PHP_versions) :

Simply use the following command while logged in as root on the server:

```
/usr/local/1h/bin/php_version.sh set [php4|php5|php51|php52|php52s|php53]
```

Where from [php4|php5|php51|php52|php52s|php53] you should choose the corresponding PHP

version you would like set as default.

This will basically do the following:

**Change the symlink for the default PHP binary in the baseos**

First change the following symlink */root/baseos/usr/bin/php*. This will adjust the baseos

setup. Note that this step only is not directly changing the current setup that is loaded

in the memory.

To switch to PHP 5.1:

```
ln -s /usr/local/php51/bin/php /root/baseos/usr/bin/php
```

To switch to PHP 5.2:

```
ln -s /usr/local/php52/bin/php /root/baseos/usr/bin/php
```

To switch to PHP 5.2 with Suhosin patch:

```
ln -s /usr/local/php52s/bin/php /root/baseos/usr/bin/php
```

**Alter the httpd.conf file to reflect the changes**

In the Apache web server configuration file (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) adjust the file

handler for PHP files. You should the corresponding line depending on the PHP version you

would like to use:

To switch to PHP 5.1:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php51 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

To switch to PHP 5.2:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

To switch to the secure PHP 5.2 with Suhosin patch:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52s .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Comment: Ahh I'm sorry I should have mentioned that because I am going through a webhosting company, I do not have access to the root

Comment: hmm i think u should ask ur  webhosting company to do this installation for u , since most of php extension installation need admin privilage.
like this command : sudo apt-get install php-pear